# How to properly bind Objects (with Sets) to Spring Forms?

Tags: java, spring, forms, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm creating a `Spring MVC` with  `Hibernate` and `JSP` and `Spring Forms`.

The annotations look like this:

**BookDescriptions.class**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "isbn", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String isbn;

private String title;
private String description;
private String price;
private String publisher;
private String pubDate;
private String edition;
private String pages;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "BookAuthorsBooks", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "isbn") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "authorId") })
private Set<BookAuthors> bookAuthors;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "BookCategoriesBooks", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "isbn") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId") })
private Set<BookCategories> bookCategories;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "BookStocksBooks", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "isbn") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "stockId") })
private BookStocks bookStock;
```

**BookStocks.class**

```
@Id
private String stockId;
private int stock;
private Date listedDate = new Date(123L);
```

**BookAuthors.class**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "authorid", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String authorId;

private String nameF;

private String nameL;
```

**BookCategories.class**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "categoryid", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int categoryId;

private String categoryName;
```

So the `BookDescriptions.class` is the parent and has a relation to the other tables using `Join Table`s.

I'm trying to manipulate data within the database through forms like that:

```
<c:forEach items="${bookDescriptions}" var="description">
            <tr>
                <form:form method="POST" action="updateStock"
                    modelAttribute="updatedStock">
                    <form:hidden path="isbn" value="${description.getIsbn()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="title" value="${description.getTitle()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="price" value="${description.getPrice()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="description"
                        value="${description.getDescription()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="publisher"
                        value="${description.getPublisher()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="pubDate"     value="${description.getPubDate()}" />    
                    <form:hidden path="edition"     value="${description.getEdition()}" />    
                    <form:hidden path="pages"     value="${description.getPages()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="bookAuthors"
                        value="${description.getBookAuthors()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="bookCategories"
                        value="${description.getBookCategories()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="bookStock"
                        value="${description.getBookStock()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="bookStock.stockId"
                          value="${description.getBookStock().getStockId()}" />

                    <td><c:out value="${description.getIsbn()}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${description.getTitle()}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${description.getBookStock().getStock()}" /></td>

                    <td><form:input path="bookStock.stock"
                                value="${description.getBookStock().getStock()}"></form:input></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
                </form:form>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

In this case it's working. I can successfully manipulate the stock but it seems I miss the proper way to bind objects to `Spring Forms` because manipulating data in `BookDescription.class` with the following form doesn't work as expected:

```
<c:forEach items="${bookDescriptions}" var="description">
            <tr>
                <form:form method="POST" action="updateStock"
                    modelAttribute="updatedBookDescription">
                    <td><form:input path="isbn" value="${description.getIsbn()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="title"
                            value="${description.getTitle()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="description"
                            value="${description.getDescription()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="publisher"
                            value="${description.getPublisher()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="price"
                            value="${description.getPrice()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="pubDate"
                            value="${description.getPubDate()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="edition"
                            value="${description.getEdition()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="pages"
                            value="${description.getPages()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="bookAuthors"
                            value="${description.getBookAuthors()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="bookCategories"
                            value="${description.getBookCategories()}" /></td>
                    <td><form:input path="bookStock"
                            value="${description.getBookStock()}" /></td>

                    <form:hidden path="bookStock.stockId"
                        value="${description.getBookStock().getStockId()}" />
                    <form:hidden path="bookStock.stock"
                        value="${description.getBookStock().getStock()}" />


                    <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
                </form:form>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

The Problem is the following: Manipulating data from the `BookDescription.class` doesn't just update the entry but deleting the old and creating a new. In this procedure the entries in the join tables are deleted and not reentered.
It seems like `Spring Forms` is not able to bind `<form:hiddenpath="bookAuthors" value="${description.getBookAuthors()}" />`.

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String adminPane(Model model) {

    List<BookDescriptions> resultList = bookDescriptionsDaoImpl.getAllEntries();
    model.addAttribute("bookDescriptions", resultList);
    model.addAttribute("updatedStock", new BookDescriptions());
    model.addAttribute("updatedBookDescription", new BookDescriptions());

    return "admin";
}
```

and the data are entered like this:

```
public void update(BookDescriptions bookDescription) {

    if (this.entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        this.entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    this.entityManager.merge(bookDescription);
    this.entityManager.flush();
    this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

At the moment I'm a little desperate because I'm missing the experience with `Hibernate` and `Spring MVC` and don't know anymore where to look for the problem/solution so I would be very thankful for keywords, solution or links for further reading.
I think I'm on the totally wrong path.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I'm using a `persistence.xml` and it looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="test-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Can you show us the file of configuration

Comment: try now and give me the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `saveOrUpdate(...);` or `update(..)` in your code like this:

```
public void update(BookDescriptions bookDescription) {

if (this.entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
    this.entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
}
this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
this.entityManager.update(bookDescription);
this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

Or

```
public void update(BookDescriptions bookDescription) {

if (this.entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
    this.entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
}
this.entityManager.saveOrUpdate(bookDescription);
}
```

Comment: my `EntityManager` doesn't have these methods. I'm using `javax.persistence.EntityManager;`. Do I need a specific interface?

Comment: when I call `${bookDescription.getBookAuthors()}` in the JSP I get the correct result so I think there is a binding problem when I try to bind this result to a new `BookDescription`